# Solving the Fibonacci series using a for loop

Tags: java

I have developed what I believe to be a novel way of coding the Fibonacci series in Java using a `for` loop. This code appears to work, but I was wondering if this is a good solution and how it could be improved.

```java
 static int loopFibonacci(int num) {
        if(num <1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("this number is not valid for fibonacci series");
        }
        int sum = 1;
        int prev = 0;
        for (int i=1;i<num;i++) {
            sum+=prev;
            prev = sum-prev;
//            System.out.println("sum="+sum+" , prev = "+prev);
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ...what I believe to be a ***novel*** way of coding the Fibonacci series...

Ahrm, no. Has been done like that forever.

---

```java
static int loopFibonacci(int num) {
```

Do not shorten variables just because you can, it makes the code harder to read and harder to maintain.

Everything without visibility modifiers is by default `package-private`. In my opinion `package-private` should be avoided as it leads very easily to hard to maintain coupling of classes and interfaces, and it is very easy to make non-extendable constructs with it.

---

```java
throw new IllegalArgumentException("this number is not valid for fibonacci series");
```

Good example of a bad error message. The error message should tell me *why* the number is not usable, what the not usable number was and what a usable number would be, for example:

```java
throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input argument must be a positive number greater or equal to 1, given <" + Integer.toString(number) + ">.");
```

---

```java
for (int i=1;i<num;i++) {
```

I'm still a very persistent advocate of the rule to only use single-letter variable names when dealing with dimensions. For "simple" for loops using `index` or `counter` improve most of the time readability quite a bit.

---

```java
sum+=prev;
```

As a note, `a += b` is not shorthand for `a = a + b` but for `a = (TYPE_A)(a + b)`, which means that it might silently truncate data, for example when adding a `float` to an `int`.

---

```java
        int sum = 1;
        int prev = 0;
        for (int i=1;i<num;i++) {
            sum+=prev;
            prev = sum-prev;
//            System.out.println("sum="+sum+" , prev = "+prev);
        }
```

Your logic is rather hard to follow, that is because before you really read it it seems to be doing something completely different. So what you want to do is clear that up, partly by using better names and partly by making the logic easier to follow:

```java
int current = 1;
int previous = 0;

for (int counter = 0; counter < steps; counter++) {
    System.out.print(current);
    System.out.println(" ");
    
    int next = current + previous;
    
    previous = current;
    current = next;
}
```

That makes it rather clear how the logic operates.

---

Looking at possible performance implications is complicated, in my opinion, but let us look at the generated bytecode before jumping to conclusions:

This is the bytecode created for original solution:

```
0: iconst_1       
1: istore_1        /* sum */
2: iconst_0       
3: istore_2        /* prev */
4: iconst_1       
5: istore_3        /* i */
6: goto            20
9: iload_1         /* sum */
10: iload_2         /* prev */
11: iadd           
12: istore_1        /* sum */
13: iload_1         /* sum */
14: iload_2         /* prev */
15: isub           
16: istore_2        /* prev */
17: iinc            i, 1
20: iload_3         /* i */
21: iload_0         /* num */
22: if_icmplt       9
25: iload_1         /* sum */
26: ireturn
```

And here is the bytecode for my revised solution:

```java
0: iconst_1       
1: istore_1        /* current */
2: iconst_0       
3: istore_2        /* previous */
4: iconst_0       
5: istore_3        /* counter */
6: goto            22
9: iload_1         /* current */
10: iload_2         /* previous */
11: iadd           
12: istore          next
14: iload_1         /* current */
15: istore_2        /* previous */
16: iload           next
18: istore_1        /* current */
19: iinc            counter, 1
22: iload_3         /* counter */
23: iload_0         /* steps */
24: if_icmplt       9
27: iload_1         /* current */
28: ireturn
```

So both solutions are using 22 instructions to accomplish their goals. After removing any noise, the difference boils down to this (original to the left):

```
13: iload_1         /* sum */        14: iload_1         /* current */
14: iload_2         /* prev */       15: istore_2        /* previous */
15: isub                             16: iload           next
16: istore_2        /* prev */       18: istore_1        /* current */
```

So the only difference is one sub operation, which we trade for a store operation. The performance difference here will be miniscule, in my opinion.

Comment: While I mostly agree with the review, you did miss the whole point of the OP's code, which is that his algorithm uses one less variable. Nowadays, that's mostly kind of a moot point, but there are still cases with embedded systems where memory is limited and algorithms like this can be quite useful.

Comment: Mh, that's true, I did not even consider it to be the point of it, to be honest. I had to spend several minutes thinking the logic through to figure out how it worked (true, I am very slow these days), and compared to how one can do it, I found this rather confusing. So my conclusion of "don't do it this way" still stands. Regarding performance, I'm not even sure *if* it is faster that way in Java, I'll have a look at that and add it to my answer.

Comment: While "faster" is one kind of optimization, "using less memory" is a different, and equally valid optimization. Though mostly forgotten, since modern computers have massive memories. My first computer was a 48k Apple II+

Comment: I do get your point, but we're talking Java here. If this would be C, or assembler, or anything close to that, I'd be with you. But Java will always be, at least for me, a "readability and maintainability"-first language, because the projects will most likely live on for years through different development teams, and most of the time companies will *depend* on the solution working. Any performance gain through such optimizations are so miniscule, that they are not worth the additional effort (and pain). If you want to optimize for memory usage, there are a ton of better ways in Java.

Comment: Well, to be honest, I'd not even be with you in C. We're talking about a 4 byte difference inside a for-loop (plus some memory management overhead) that should not run for an extended period of time. There are places for that kind of optimization, somebody starting out in programming is for sure not in any of those places (I hope for them, at least). So is it an optimization? Yes, the bytecode tells me so (traded storing for an operation). Is it worth to ever think about it (in Java)? No, absolutely not. Should we tell people to optimize like that in Java? Absolutely not!

Comment: I agree with you that 99.999999999% of the time, this would be a silly optimization and best avoided. I've found that even the strangest and most unlikely of algorithms manage to find uses though.

Comment: @Bobby What is the additional memory management overhead from adding one local variable? They are stored in stack so it should go into the constant time operation of the method call (e.g. no overhead), right?

Comment: @TorbenPutkonen Well, to be honest, pulled that out of my ass because I was unsure whether a pointer is required or not (yes, I suck at low-level stuff, I'm a Java guy through and through).

Comment: @Donald.McLean As I've said, I'm with you there, I understand what you mean. I just fail to see *any* value regarding that in this question/situation.